# NHibernate hierarchical recursive query

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, nhibernate, orm

i am using NHibernate ORM with MySql database for my APP. i am using simple nested table model for my categories.

my table sql :

```
CREATE TABLE `cat` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `catId` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `dr` bit(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `st` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=25 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

my category class:

```
   public class cat
    {
        [Key]
        public virtual int id { get; set; }
        public virtual int catId { get; set; }
        public virtual bool dr { get; set; }
        public virtual DateTime st { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("catId")]
        public virtual IList<cat> cats { get; set; }
    }
```

How can i do this query with NH :

```
select t2.* from (select id from cat where catId=0 and dr=1) t1 join 
cat t2 On(t1.id=t2.catId) where t2.st<Now() and t2.dr=1;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    using NHibernate;
    using NHibernate.Criterion;
    using NHibernate.Linq;
    using NHibernate.Transform;
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
```

..........

```
            var q2 = db.Query<cat>()
                .Where(x => x.catId== 0 && x.dr == true);

            q2 = from t1 in q2
                 join t2 in db.Query<cat>() on t1.id equals t2.catId
                 where t2.st< DateTime.Now && t2.dr== true
                 select t2;

            //for result list
            var myList = q2.ToList();
```

i can do that query with NHibernate & Linq. May be it can be help some one.